# Incorrect job interval when using HangFire

Tags: c#, console-application, hangfire

I have 2 simple jobers `GetMenuJober` and `GetOrdersJober`. All they do is printing message in console, `RunJob` method is similar in both classes:

```
public async Task RunJob()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType().Name} has been started.");
}
```

I planned to start these workers in 5 seconds:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<GetOrdersJober>(x => x.RunJob(), "0/5 * * * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<GetMenuJober>(x => x.RunJob(), "0/5 * * * * *");
```

And expected to see something like this in the console:

```
GetOrdersJober has been started.
GetMenuJober has been started.
GetOrdersJober has been started.
GetMenuJober has been started.
GetOrdersJober has been started.
GetMenuJober has been started.
```

The intervals between the launches of both are different, while they are not equal to 5 seconds, sometimes 30, sometimes more than a minute. Jobs run completely different. What did I miss ?

[image]

Moreover, even if I set cron expression as `Cron.Minutely` both jobs will run in absolutely random interval.

Comment: you want to run both jobs each 5 seconds?

Comment: @viveknuna yes exactly